# Move multiple files iteratively in Pyspark from a list

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-data-lake

I want to move multiple files one after another by reaming them by concatenating with a counter  in Pyspark in Azure data lake storage below is the code but I am unable to run this command iteratively. it just moves one file out of 20 part files.

```
import os
cnt = 0 
file_list = [file.path for file in dbutils.fs.ls("Soure_Path") 
  if os.path.basename(file.path).startswith("part-")]

for i in file_list:
 cnt = cnt +1
 dbutils.fs.mv(i, "Target_Path" + "Filename_" + str(cnt) + ".csv")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like python code..where are are using pyspark

Comment: I am using the code in databricks whichever way it works, i am fine be it pyspark or python.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me and I was able to rename and move files to target folder.

Doublecheck if you have more than 1 file which starts with "**part**" filename.

**Input**:

[image]

```
import os
cnt = 0 

file_list = [file.path for file in dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/Input/") 
  if os.path.basename(file.path).startswith("part-")]
#print(file_list)

for i in file_list:
cnt = cnt +1
dbutils.fs.mv(i, "abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/output/" + "Filename_" + str(cnt) + ".csv")
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes it works fine for one part file but I want to move 20 part files in loop one after another and that’s not happening

Comment: I tried to move more that1 file (see my Input and Output screenshots) with this code and was successful. Isn't this what you are expecting? Also can you please share a sample of your file names?

Comment: I have multiple part files in the below format but with my code only the last file from the list gets moved. File names are like this part-00000-tid-xxx, part-00001-tid-yyyy, part-00002-zzzz